# What does $E_L$ mean in the context of shading equations from the book "Real time rendering"?

Tags: rendering, lighting, shading

[image: Equation 5.10 from Real Time Rendering book]

> We will use $E_L$ for irradiance perpendicular to $l$

Where $l$ is the light vector.

What does this mean? How do I calculate $E_L$?

Comment: For reference: Previously asked 2 hours earlier [on an external site](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/680892-does-anyone-know-what-el-means-in-the-context-of-shading-equations-from-the-book-real-time-rendering/)

Comment: I've edited the title to include MathJax to show the subscript. If anyone finds this causes a problem please contribute to the [discussion on meta](http://meta.computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/238/should-we-use-mathjax-latex-in-question-titles).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line you quoted says it: $E_L$ is the incoming [irradiance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irradiance) at the surface due to the light source under consideration. Less technically, it's a vector representing the intensity and color of the incoming light at that point.

The equation you mention is for a punctual light source (directional, point, or spot light), so in this case $E_L$ would simply be the user-defined RGB color of the light source, multiplied by any relevant attenuation factors—such as shadows, distance attenuation for point/spot lights, and cone angle attenuation for spot lights.

Comment: wasn't the original `El` name derived from "emissive light" ? which was not a convolved term, but an additive term in front of the integral. Irradiance should be named `Ir` no ?

Comment: @v.oddou E is the usual variable for irradiance that I've seen used in texts and papers. Emissive light is usually denoted $L_e$ (L is radiance).